# Avoid re-rendering HUD / GUI elements every frame

Tags: c++, opengl

Rendering sophisticated HUD elements (everything ranging from compass to health bar) and especially widgets like text boxes takes a lot of FPS away in my game.

- Is there a way I can pre-draw the GUI, cache it and blend it over the world space each frame? (And update the cache when it's needed)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, render the HUD to textures with an alpha channel, then when you draw your scene, just put a quad with the textures on it.  You can use [frame buffer objects](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html) to render to a texture.

*NOTE:* you don't need to use the _EXT, since frame buffer objects are now part of the OpenGL standard.  You can also get more information [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object)